# How are the 3D axes arranged?

Tags: 3d

I'm trying to figure out how to create mesh in Unity and I keep going back to the question: Does the Z axis go vertically or horizontally?

Comment: It depends. In some domains, main reference plane is terrain with XY plane and Z going up (think Warcraft), in other domains main plane could be "from a side", with Y being up and XZ groundplane (think SuperMario).

Comment: Just an FYI, it is not obvious that this question is referring to Unity's co-ord system as Unity is not in the title of the question, nor are there any relavant tags. I can understand why @Kromster has missed this and seems to be answering the general question about which way is which.

In Unity, there is a definitive answer to this which I've answered here.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite easy to see in the scene as soon as you open the editor.

By default, Unity's axes are arranged as follows:

- `X` = right (red arrow)
- `Y` = up (green arrow)
- `Z` = forward (blue arrow)

AKA: a Left Hand Co-ordinate system.

[image: Image of Unity scene with camera selected]

Gravity is also, by default, set to -9.81 along the `Y` axis, and the the camera is orientated with its top pointing along the positive `Y` axis and facing along the positive `Z` axis.

Which way is which can obviously change depending on how the scene is set up, but the aforementioned default setup has the aforementioned orientations.

To answer your question, the `Z` axis goes vertically, positive in the upward direction and negative in the downward direction.